# "Error! Missing Or invalid Action name" Etherscan API error

Tags: etherscan, web3.py

I created a utility in my function to get the status of transactions using Etherscan APIs. It was working well until recently. Here's the function:

```
def get_eth_or_usdt_transaction_status(transaction_hash, currency):
    action = "gettxreceiptstatus" if currency == ETHEREUM else "getstatus"

    url = f"{etherscan_base_url}?module=transaction&action={action}\
        &txhash={transaction_hash}&apikey={settings.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY}"
    url = strip_str(url, "url")

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
    return response
```

The fucntion above returns:

```
{
    'status': '0',
    'message': 'NOTOK',
    'result': 'Error! Missing Or invalid Action name'
}
```

Nothing actually changed in the code. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Try using this header

```
'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

It throws that error if you use 'Content-Type': "application/json"